# PHP socket_recv retrieves no Multicast data

Tags: php, windows, multicast

I am trying to read Multicast Data send by SMA EMeter under Windows Server 2016 (PHP Version 7.1)

```
    // Listen to Multicast
    $port = 9522 ;  // Multicast Port used by SMA
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    echo "Read SMA Energymeter ->  socket creation done: ".$socket."\n"; 
    $bindip="0.0.0.0"; // local unspecified
    if(!socket_bind($socket,$bindip,$port)) {echo "Read SMA Energymeter ->  bind failed\n"; exit();  }
    echo "Read SMA Energymeter ->  bind on port: ".$port." ip: ".$bindip." done\n";

    $adress = "239.12.255.254"; // Multicast IP used by SMA
    $ret=socket_set_option($socket,IPPROTO_IP,MCAST_JOIN_GROUP,array("group"=>$adress,"interface"=>0));
    if ($ret === false) {echo "Read SMA Energymeter -> Unable to join multicast group";exit();  }
    echo "Read SMA Energymeter ->  MCAST join sucessfully done: ".$adress."\n";   

    $fromport= 0;
    $flags   = 0 ;
    $from = '';//"192.168.1.116" ;
    $raw = "That is the return buffer";
    $len = 700 ; // sind rund 600 Bytes vom SMA zu erwarten

    echo "Read SMA Energymeter ->  start retrieval. Len:".$len."\n";        
    $bytes=socket_recvfrom($socket,$raw,$len,$flags,$from,$fromport);
    //$bytes=socket_recv($socket,$raw,$len,$flags);
    echo "Read SMA Energymeter ->  socket recieved done. Bytes:".$bytes."\n";
```

Problem socket_recv never returns. Looks like no data retrieved. Wireshark shows 1-2 packets (each 600Bytes) [1] comming in every second. Perf monitor shows that php is listening on port 9522 [2].

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjYYa.png [1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uQqt.png [2]

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: the output currently looks like
Read SMA Energymeter ->  socket creation done: Resource id #4
Read SMA Energymeter ->  bind on port: 9522 ip: 0.0.0.0 done
Read SMA Energymeter ->  MCAST join done: 239.12.255.254
Read SMA Energymeter ->  start retrieval. Len:700

Comment: no one with an idea what might be wrong with the code snippet?

Comment: Tested a bit further using wireshark - looks like the wrong interface is used as the script sends out the join towards local network 192.168.0.0 (LAN) instead of using the 192.168.1.0 (WAN) network.  I tried to change interface to "1" but still LAN is used. Any idea how to properly set this under windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that under windows the outgoing MC IF is based on the routing table.
If you use multiple NICs you need to delete the MC routes and add it on the IF you would like to use. Like in my case:

```
route delete 224.0.0.0 mask 240.0.0.0
route add 224.0.0.0 mask 240.0.0.0 192.168.1.63
```

obviously other applications that might require to send the MCAST on the previous if will no longer work :(

Comment: maybe more elegant: change the metric of the interfaces to prioritize your wanted multicast one